# Prove that if $f:[0,1)\to(0,1)$ surjective and continuous then $f(x)=y$ has infinitely many solutions, for $y\in(0,1)$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $f:[0,1)\to(0,1)$ be a function that is surjective and continuous. Show that $\forall y \in (0,1),f(x)-y = 0$ must have infinitely many solutions.

The function is surjective, so there is at least one solution. Now suppose there are finitely many solutions for the equation. I'm thinking that I should use the intermediate value theorem, to show that between the last assumed solution and 1 there is one more solution, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: If $y\in (0, 1)$ is such that there are only finitely many solutions to $f(x) = y$, let $x_m$ be the largest of those solutions. What can you say about the image of $f$ restricted to $[0, x_m]$?

Comment: I think I got it. The image of the restriction is bounded and closed. We can choose two numbers a,b such that they are outside the image, one smaller than the lower bound, one bigger than the upper bound. Now because of surjectivity there must be two numbers $a_1,a_2$ in $(x_m,1)$ such that $f(a_1)=a,f(a_2)=b$. Using IVT, $f([a_1,a_2])$ is an interval that contains y, which contradicts my initial assumption.

Comment: @Ban Yes, that's exactly it. You could not explicit about the fact that $0<a<b<1$ (in particular $a,b\in(0,1)$), but otherwise that's perfect.

Comment: *You could be more explicit. Damn mobile keyboard.